# How can pass ref property to component in emotion js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, emotion-js

I'm using emotionJs for styled component in my project , I want to pass ref property to my emotion styled component , how can I do that?

```js
import styled from '@emotion/styled';
const Page = styled.section<PaperProps>(({ theme, color = 'paper' }) => ({
  backgroundColor: color && theme.palette.background[color],
  color: theme.palette.background.contrastText,
  padding: theme.spacing(2),
  borderRadius: theme.radius.default,
}));

export default Page;
```

when I get my ref variable it returns null :

```js
const myRef = createRef();
<Page ref={myRef}> 
....
</Page>
```

Comment: And whats the problem? This is how you pass a ref, emotions handles it normally

Comment: @DennisVash when I consoled this it returns the current null and in my vs
code show a red line for my ref prop and show this text (Type 'RefObject<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLElement> | undefined'.
  Type 'RefObject<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLElement>'.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'HTMLElement')

Comment: It doesn't help much pasting errors without useable code, please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)